# Nesting list within a list that are different types

Tags: c#, linq

I currently have dummy classes that represent data that would be queried from the database. The first one is a main table that has one to one foreign keys to other tables:

```
public class PayslipMain
    {
        public int payslip_date_ID;
        public int employee_no_ID;
        public string scale_description;
        public string scale_point;
        public double current_rate;
        public string cost_centre;
        public string message;
        public string pension_message;
        public int gross_earnings_ID;
        public int deductions_ID;
        public int details_ID;
        public int cumulatives_ID;

        public PayslipMain()
        {

        }

    public PayslipMain(int payslipdateid, int employeenoid, string scaledescription, string scalepoint, double ratecurrent, string costcentre, string _message, string pensionmessage, int grossearnings_id, int deductions_id, int details_id, int cumulatives_id)
    {
        payslip_date_ID = payslipdateid;
        employee_no_ID = employeenoid;
        scale_description = scaledescription;
        scale_description = scalepoint;
        current_rate = ratecurrent;
        cost_centre = costcentre;
        gross_earnings_ID = grossearnings_id;
        deductions_ID = deductions_id;
        details_ID = details_id;
        cumulatives_ID = cumulatives_id;
        message = _message;
        pension_message = pensionmessage;

    }

}
```

These classes are then used to create a dynamic list of information:

```
public List<PayslipMain> BuildPayslip()
        {
            List<PayslipMain> list = new List<PayslipMain>();

            list.Add(new PayslipMain(0, "Grade 8 (Professional S)", "43", 45954.00, "Default Cost Centre", "TAX REF: 065/L11408", "There is no historic message stored for this payslip.", 1, 1, 1, 1));
            list.Add(new PayslipMain(1, "Grade 8 (Professional S)", "43", 50000.00, "Default Cost Centre", "TAX REF: 065/L11408", "There is no historic message stored for this payslip.", 2, 2, 2, 2));

            return list;
        }
```

However, for the last four values, I am trying to add a nested list into where those values are based on the one to one relationships. E.g.

```
public class Details
    {
        public int details_Id;
        public string details_element;
        public string details_value;

        public Details()
        {

        }

        public Details(int detailsid, string detailselement, string detailsvalue)
        {
            details_Id = detailsid;
            details_element = detailselement;
            details_value = detailsvalue;
        }
    }
}
```

Then this class is used to create:

```
public List<Details> BuildList()
        {
            List<Details> list = new List<Details>();

            /* 28th September 2015 */
            list.Add(new Details(1, "Pay Group", "1"));
            list.Add(new Details(1, "Personnel No.", "025946"));
            list.Add(new Details(1, "National Insurance No.", "NS000000D"));
            list.Add(new Details(1, "National Insurance Letter", "D"));
            list.Add(new Details(1, "Tax Basis", "Cumulative"));
            list.Add(new Details(1, "Tax Code", "1060L"));

            /* 28th September 2015 */
            list.Add(new Details(2, "Pay Group", "8"));
            list.Add(new Details(2, "Personnel No.", "442685"));
            list.Add(new Details(2, "National Insurance No.", "NS000000D"));
            list.Add(new Details(2, "National Insurance Letter", "J"));
            list.Add(new Details(2, "Tax Basis", "Cumulative"));
            list.Add(new Details(2, "Tax Code", "9204L"));

            return list;
        }
```

The other lists are created the same as this one, but with different keys for different values.

So is it possible to nest these lists to the main one where the foreign key is the id in each list?

Add list within a list:

```
public List<PayslipMain> BuildPayslip()
        {
            List<PayslipMain> list = new List<PayslipMain>();

            list.Add(new PayslipMain(0, 12345, "Grade 8 (Professional S)", "43", 45954.00, "Default Cost Centre", "TAX REF: 065/L11408", "There is no historic message stored for this payslip.", 1, 1, 1, 1));
            list.Add(new PayslipMain(1, 12345, "Grade 8 (Professional S)", "43", 50000.00, "Default Cost Centre", "TAX REF: 065/L11408", "There is no historic message stored for this payslip.", 2, 2, 2, 2));

            return list;
        }
```

Where the 1 or 2 is the foriegn key of another list:

```
public List<Details> BuildList()
        {
            List<Details> list = new List<Details>();

            /* 28th September 2015 */
            list.Add(new Details(1, "Pay Group", "1"));
            list.Add(new Details(1, "Personnel No.", "025946"));
            list.Add(new Details(1, "National Insurance No.", "NS000000D"));
            list.Add(new Details(1, "National Insurance Letter", "D"));
            list.Add(new Details(1, "Tax Basis", "Cumulative"));
            list.Add(new Details(1, "Tax Code", "1060L"));

            /* 28th September 2015 */
            list.Add(new Details(2, "Pay Group", "8"));
            list.Add(new Details(2, "Personnel No.", "442685"));
            list.Add(new Details(2, "National Insurance No.", "NS000000D"));
            list.Add(new Details(2, "National Insurance Letter", "J"));
            list.Add(new Details(2, "Tax Basis", "Cumulative"));
            list.Add(new Details(2, "Tax Code", "9204L"));

            return list;
        }
```

I wish to add the details list onto the payslip main list where the foreign key is the value

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you want to do. Do you want to pass 4 lists to the constructor of PayslipMain?

Comment: Hi, I'm after adding the 'Details' list to its foreign key in 'PayslipMain' as a nested list

Comment: Adding in PayslipMain a property like "public List<Details> DetailsList {get;set;}" does not work?

Comment: Add an instance of the List<Details> directly to the PayslipMain object. Then call myPayslipMain.TheDetailList.Add(Details)

Comment: If they are one-to-one relationships, why don't you just do something like `public Details PaylistMainDetails {get; set; }`

Comment: Do you want to nest a List of Lists. Inside another generic list?

Comment: Specific typed list within a specific typed list

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have many Details (etc) per PayslipMain instance, do something like this:

```
public class PayslipMain
{
    // your properties...
    public int cumulatives_ID;
    public List<Details> PayslipMainDetails { get; private set; }
}

public PayslipMain(/* your params...*/)
{
    // your assignings...
    pension_message = pensionmessage;
    PayslipMainDetails = new List<Details>();
}

// wherever you create your list of details, do this
payslipMainInstance.PayslipMainDetails.AddRange(BuildList());
```

Comment: This is good, but I'm after nesting the Details list dependent on the foreign key.

Comment: @user3565164 what do you even mean by "nesting"? Show a pseudo-code example.

Comment: Add another list where the foriegn key is the same as the id in the added list - see updated question

Comment: C# Lists don't have "foreign keys" nor the idea of what they are. Maybe what you want is to add a `List<PayslipMain>` to PayslipMain?